# React Native SQLite Full Text Search

Tags: sqlite, react-native, full-text-search, fts3, fts4

I'm trying to implement full-text search with SQLite in React Native. I'm using `react-native-sqlite-storage`. Android doesn't support FTS5. But, I've been able to create a virtual table and run queries using FTS4. The problem is ranking the search results. The only function that FTS3 and FTS4 provide you with is `matchinfo()`, which returns a `blob`. In order to be able to rank the results you need to create a user-defined function, like explained at the bottom of this [page](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#appendix_a).

The question is how can I create that function while using `react-native-sqlite-storage`? Is that even possible? If not, is there any other solution? Full-text search without ranking is kind of useless.